Collect list is not working as expected in the subquery with spark
I want to form a spark SQL query. I have 2 tables, one raw table and another one is a namespace table. There is an array column in the raw table and there are 2 columns in the namespace table key and value. Now I want to filter out rows from the raw table where the value is let's say 'abc' and the key of the namespace is in the raw table array column.
I tried using subquery and arrays_overlap like the following
SELECT
  *
FROM
  raw_table
WHERE
  (
    (
      arrays_overlap(
        raw_table_array_column,(
          SELECT
            collect_list(
              CAST(`key` AS int)
            )
          FROM
            namespaceName AS alias
          WHERE
            alias.`value` IN (‘ abc ’)
        )
      )
    )
  )

But, this is giving me an empty result, but if I only do the inner query separately I can find there are some values. Can anyone find out where is this query wrong or suggest any other approach to tackle this?
P.S: The Spark version used here is 2.4.0 and I can only use SQL query and cannot use dataframe operations.
